# Multiple overlays vs continous redrawing im MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am drawing users location path on MKMapView live and I am wondering what's better approach.

Currently I am gathering all location data in location manager and I am redrawing whole overlay every second.

```
- (void)showLines {
    NSArray *locations = [[SHLocationManager sharedInstance] locations];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *pointsCoordinate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D *)malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * locations.count);
    [locations enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLLocation *location, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        pointsCoordinate[idx] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
    }];

    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsCoordinate count:locations.count];
    free(pointsCoordinate);

    [self.mapView removeOverlays:self.mapView.overlays];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
}

- (MKPolylineRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay{
    MKPolylineRenderer *polylineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.17 green:0.57 blue:0.85 alpha:1];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 8.0;
    polylineView.alpha = 1;

    return polylineView;
}
```

Is it better to draw a line for every pair of point's I get from location manager?

It would create number of overlays - don't know how it would affect performance.

What's better in your opinion?